# How to sequence observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

How do you coordinate observable sequences so one starts only when the other is finished?

I have 3 observable of different types:

```
var obs1 = ...
var obs2 = ...
var obs2 = ...
```

I want to do:

```
obs1.Subscribe( () => obs2.Subscribe( ()=> obs3.Subscribe( () => /* Hide Progress */ )));
```

But this code is really ugly. Is there some operator to do it? I tried using the `And()` extension method but I'm not sure that this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind introducing TPL, you can just use `await`:

```
await obs1;
await obs2;
await obs3;
```

If you want to observe the values of each while still using await, just add `Do`:

```
await obs1.Do(t1 => ...);
await obs2.Do(t2 => ...);
await obs3.Do(t3 => ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
obs1
    .Concat(obs2)
    .Concat(obs3)
    .Subscribe(x => /* ... */ );
```

Obviously this only works with cold observables. If your `obs2` & `obs3` are hot you might miss values.

Comment: No, for concat to work the observables must be of same type (return the same type). My observables are of different types. What I need is more like a .ContinueWith()

Answer (score 0):

Enigmativity is correct, though you just have to use `Select` also.

```
obs1.Select(t => new { t, (U)null, (V)null })
    .Concat(
obs2.Select(u => new { (T)null, u, (V)null }))
    .Concat(
obs3.Select(v => new { (T)null, (U)null, v }))
    .Subscribe(either =>
     {
       if (either.t != null) Observe(either.t);
       else if (either.u != null) Observe(either.u);
       else if (either.v != null) Observe(either.v);
       else { throw new Exception("Oops."); }
     })
```

See also a related blog post of mine: [The Power of T](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Rx-The-Power-of-T.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in observing obs3, you may want to write like this:

```
        obs1.TakeLast(1)
            .SelectMany(x => obs2)
            .TakeLast(1)
            .SelectMany(y => obs3)
            .Subscribe(z => ... );  // z is the same type of obs3's data type
```

We take the last item from obs1 and when it arrives, we use SelectMany to subscribe to and output obs2. Then we repeatedly taking the last item from the returned Observable, and when the last item arrives, we again use SelectMany to subscribe to and output obs3. Afterwards you can subscribe to the returned Observable and do the handling of obs3 as you like.